# Apache Nutch 1.11 Running on Hadoop 2.7 cluster, gives worng fs

Tags: hadoop, ant, nutch

Hadoop 2.7 cluster was running well,tested by running WordCount Problem.
Now I am trying to run an Apache Nutch crawler on my hadoop cluster. 
 
Step I completed :-

> a) Download Apache Nutch 1.11 
>   b) Change conf file as it requires 
>   c) Build nutch by Ant 
>   d) Run apache-nutch-1.11.job by Running following command:-
>   hadoop jar apache-nutch-1.11.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector      /user/hduser/nutchData /user/hduser/urls

gives me following error:-

```
ERROR crawl.Injector: Injector: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   Wrong FS: hdfs://master:9000/user/hduser/nutchData/333860923, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:646)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:604)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1437)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.rename(ChecksumFileSystem.java:506)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.install(CrawlDb.java:169)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:354)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: do you get anything different with :

cd runtime/deploy/bin
nutch inject nutchData urls

?

Comment: Does the command 'hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser' work?

Comment: Sorry for late :D 
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser' worked properly.